# Css selectors - a:visited childs

Tags: css

I'm able to select child of `a` like so:

```
a > img {
/*change something*/
}
```

But I want first select `a:visited`, than its child. Something like:

```
a:visited > img {
/*change something*/
}
```

But the latter seems not working.

---

Example of HTML. Want change appearance of the image (adding border `border: 2px solid;` for example), if it is visited.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body id="body-html">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56418220/css-selectors-avisited-childs?noredirect=1#comment99432271_56418220" class="test">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzzXb.png">
  </a>
</body>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Paulie_D html example added. Check it please. Do I need to add/amend something else?

Comment: a:visited has very few option possible nowdays, to avoid sites to find out where you've been before even if you set your browser not to tell ...

Comment: @G-Cyr i see, privacy issue.. But does it mean the answer is - 'There is no way to do it at all'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most CSS rules on `:visited` links have been blocked for [security reasons](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/).
However, you can still apply `border-color` to them.

The only gotcha here is that the border must be also applied on non-visited links, since you can only change the `border-color`.

```
a img {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

a:visited img {
  border-color: green;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ecwd5tm/)

Comment: I think it will be enough for now, thx! Shame it seems like doesn't accept `border: 2px solid;` inside `a:visited img`.

Answer (score 1):

> Though direct styling for :visited links is limited, there are lots of clever ways to extend your options for styling visited links. In 2015 there was a bumper crop of blog posts sharing new ideas for styling :visited links:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/